# MergeSort in scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I came across another [codechef problem](http://www.codechef.com/problems/INSOMA3) which I am attempting to solve in Scala. The problem statement is as follows:

> Stepford Street was a dead end street. The houses on Stepford Street
>   were bought by wealthy millionaires. They had them extensively altered
>   so that as one progressed along the street, the height of the
>   buildings increased rapidly. However, not all millionaires were
>   created equal. Some refused to follow this trend and kept their houses
>   at their original heights. The resulting progression of heights was
>   thus disturbed. A contest to locate the most ordered street was
>   announced by the Beverly Hills Municipal Corporation. The criteria for
>   the most ordered street was set as follows: If there exists a house
>   with a lower height later in the street than the house under
>   consideration, then the pair (current house, later house) counts as 1
>   point towards the disorderliness index of the street. It is not
>   necessary that the later house be adjacent to the current house. Note:
>   No two houses on a street will be of the same height For example, for
>   the input: 1 2 4 5 3 6 The pairs (4,3), (5,3) form disordered pairs.
>   Thus the disorderliness index of this array is 2. As the criteria for
>   determining the disorderliness is complex, the BHMC has requested your
>   help to automate the process. You need to write an efficient program
>   that calculates the disorderliness index of a street.

A sample input output provided is as follows:

> Input: 1 2 4 5 3 6
>
> Output: 2

The output is 2 because of two pairs (4,3) and (5,3)

To solve this problem I thought I should use a variant of MergeSort,incrementing by 1 when the left element is greater than the right element.

My scala code is as follows:

```
    def dysfunctionCalc(input:List[Int]):Int = {
        val leftHalf = input.size/2
        println("HalfSize:"+leftHalf)

        val isOdd = input.size%2
        println("Is odd:"+isOdd)

        val leftList = input.take(leftHalf+isOdd)
        println("LeftList:"+leftList)

        val rightList = input.drop(leftHalf+isOdd)
        println("RightList:"+rightList)

        if ((leftList.size <= 1) && (rightList.size <= 1)){
                println("Entering input where both lists are <= 1")
                             if(leftList.size == 0 || rightList.size == 0){
                                      println("One of the lists is less than 0")
                                        0
                                }
                             else if(leftList.head > rightList.head)1 else 0
     }       
     else{
             println("Both lists are greater than 1")
             dysfunctionCalc(leftList) + dysfunctionCalc(rightList)
     }
   }
```

First off, my logic is wrong,it doesn't have a merge stage and I am not sure what would be the best way to percolate the result of the base-case up the stack and compare it with the other values. Also, using recursion to solve this problem may not be the most optimal way to go since for large lists, I maybe blowing up the stack. Also, there might be stylistic issues with my code as well.

I would be great if somebody could point out other flaws and the right way to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: first stylistic issue: fix the indentation so your code is readable

Comment: You can look at merge sort implementation (Listing 16.1) from [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/working-with-lists.html#16.6)

Comment: What would be the pairs for: 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 ?

Comment: (2,1),(2,1),(3,1),(3,2),(3,1),(3,2),(2,1),(3,1),(3,2)

Comment: @dhg - Thanks for pointing that out. I put some tabs in, hope its a little more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you split your list into three pieces: the item you are considering, those on the left, and those on the right.  Suppose further that those on the left are in a sorted set.  Now you just need to walk through the list, moving items from "right" to "considered" and from "considered" to "left"; at each point, you look at the size of the subset of the sorted set that is greater than your item.  In general, the size lookup can be done in `O(log(N))` as can the add-element (with a Red-Black or AVL tree, for instance).  So you have `O(N log N)` performance.

Now the question is how to implement this in Scala efficiently.  It turns out that Scala has a Red-Black tree used for its `TreeSet` sorted set, and the implementation is actually quite simple (here in tail-recursive form):

```
import collection.immutable.TreeSet
final def calcDisorder(xs: List[Int], left: TreeSet[Int] = TreeSet.empty, n: Int = 0): Int = xs match {
  case Nil => n
  case x :: rest => calcDisorder(rest, left + x, n + left.from(x).size)
}
```

Unfortunately, `left.from(x).size` takes `O(N)` time (I believe), which yields a quadratic execution time.  That's no good--what you need is an `IndexedTreeSet` which can do `indexOf(x)` in `O(log(n))` (and then iterate with `n + left.size - left.indexOf(x) - 1`).  You can build your own implementation or find one on the web.  For instance, I found one [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/milch/blog/software.html) ([API here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/milch/blog/apidocs/common/IndexedTreeSet.html)) for Java that does exactly the right thing.

Incidentally, the problem with doing a mergesort is that you cannot easily work cumulatively.  With merging a pair, you can keep track of how out-of-order it is.  But when you merge in a third list, you must see how out of order it is *with respect to both other lists*, which spoils your divide-and-conquer strategy.  (I am not sure whether there is some invariant one could find that would allow you to calculate directly if you kept track of it.)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really think about the out of orderness of merging multiple lists in divide-and-conquer. Thanks for pointing that out. I will try to look for an IndexedTreeSet in scala or maybe implementing it will be my next project.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my try, I don't use MergeSort but it seems to solve the problem:

```
def calcDisorderness(myList:List[Int]):Int = myList match{
  case Nil => 0
  case t::q => q.count(_<t) + calcDisorderness(q)
}
```

> scala> val input = List(1,2,4,5,3,6)
>
> input: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6)
>
> scala> calcDisorderness(input)
>
> res1: Int = 2

The question is, is there a way to have a lower complexity?

**Edit:** tail recursive version of the same function and cool usage of default values in function arguments.

```
def calcDisorderness(myList:List[Int], disorder:Int=0):Int = myList match{
  case Nil => disorder
  case t::q => calcDisorderness(q, disorder + q.count(_<t))
}
```

Comment: @ChirsJamesC - I really like your approach. Its very elegant. As far as the time complexity goes, this is quadratic, right?

Comment: I made my answer more concise but it doesn't change the complecity which is quadric as you said.

Comment: I am saying this out of ignorance but how is your second version tail-recursive but your first version isn't?

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on Merge Sort. Not super fast, potential slowdown could be in "xs.length".

```
def countSwaps(a: Array[Int]): Long = {
    var disorder: Long = 0

    def msort(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = { 
        import Stream._
        def merge(left: List[Int], right: List[Int], inc: Int): Stream[Int] = {
            (left, right) match {
                case (x :: xs, y :: ys) if x > y =>
                    cons(y, merge(left, ys, inc + 1))
                case (x :: xs, _) => {
                    disorder += inc
                    cons(x, merge(xs, right, inc))
                }
                case _ => right.toStream
            }
        }

        val n = xs.length / 2 
        if (n == 0)
            xs 
        else { 
            val (ys, zs) = xs splitAt n 
            merge(msort(ys), msort(zs), 0).toList
        } 
    }

    msort(a.toList)
    disorder
}
```

Comment: And possibly in "xs splitAt n".

Comment: Thanks. That's an interesting solution. Would it be possible to elaborate on why you are using cons instead of '::'? And also would there be better if the mergestep is made tail-recursive?

Comment: Ah..I see the point of using cons. By using cons you are lazily evaluating the entire sequence without the overhead of storing the entire structure in memory. Its a pretty cool solution

Answer (score 1):

Another solution based on Merge Sort. Very fast: no FP or for-loop.

```
def countSwaps(a: Array[Int]): Count = {
    var swaps: Count = 0

    def mergeRun(begin: Int, run_len: Int, src: Array[Int], dst: Array[Int]) = {
        var li = begin
        val lend = math.min(begin + run_len, src.length)
        var ri = begin + run_len
        val rend = math.min(begin + run_len * 2, src.length)

        var ti = begin
        while (ti < rend) {
            if (ri >= rend) {
                dst(ti) = src(li); li += 1
                swaps += ri - begin - run_len
            } else if (li >= lend) {
                dst(ti) = src(ri); ri += 1
            } else if (a(li) <= a(ri)) {
                dst(ti) = src(li); li += 1
                swaps += ri - begin - run_len
            } else {
                dst(ti) = src(ri); ri += 1
            }
            ti += 1
        }
    }

    val b = new Array[Int](a.length)
    var run = 0
    var run_len = 1
    while (run_len < a.length) {
        var begin = 0
        while (begin < a.length) {
            val (src, dst) = if (run % 2 == 0) (a, b) else (b, a)
            mergeRun(begin, run_len, src, dst)
            begin += run_len * 2
        }
        run += 1
        run_len *= 2
    }

    swaps
}
```

Convert the above code to Functional style: no mutable variable, no loop.
All recursions are tail calls, thus the performance is good.

```
def countSwaps(a: Array[Int]): Count = {
    def mergeRun(li: Int, lend: Int, rb: Int, ri: Int, rend: Int, di: Int, src: Array[Int], dst: Array[Int], swaps: Count): Count = {
        if (ri >= rend && li >= lend) {
            swaps
        } else if (ri >= rend) {
            dst(di) = src(li)
            mergeRun(li + 1, lend, rb, ri, rend, di + 1, src, dst, ri - rb + swaps)
        } else if (li >= lend) {
            dst(di) = src(ri)
            mergeRun(li, lend, rb, ri + 1, rend, di + 1, src, dst, swaps)
        } else if (src(li) <= src(ri)) {
            dst(di) = src(li)
            mergeRun(li + 1, lend, rb, ri, rend, di + 1, src, dst, ri - rb + swaps)
        } else {
            dst(di) = src(ri)
            mergeRun(li, lend, rb, ri + 1, rend, di + 1, src, dst, swaps)
        }
    }

    val b = new Array[Int](a.length)

    def merge(run: Int, run_len: Int, lb: Int, swaps: Count): Count = {
        if (run_len >= a.length) {
            swaps
        } else if (lb >= a.length) {
            merge(run + 1, run_len * 2, 0, swaps)
        } else {
            val lend = math.min(lb + run_len, a.length)
            val rb = lb + run_len
            val rend = math.min(rb + run_len, a.length)
            val (src, dst) = if (run % 2 == 0) (a, b) else (b, a)
            val inc_swaps = mergeRun(lb, lend, rb, rb, rend, lb, src, dst, 0)
            merge(run, run_len, lb + run_len * 2, inc_swaps + swaps)
        }
    }

    merge(0, 1, 0, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the key is to break the list into a series of ascending sequences.  For example, your example would be broken into (1 2 4 5)(3 6).  None of the items in the first list can end a pair.  Now you do a kind of merge of these two lists, working backwards:

- 6 > 5, so 6 can't be in any pairs
- 3 < 5, so its a pair
- 3 < 4, so its a pair
- 3 > 2, so we're done

I'm not clear from the definition on how to handle more than 2 such sequences.